# How producer can access the acknowledgement sent by message broker?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have below code in main method. I am not getting how i can check the acknowledgment sent from message broker . Basically i want to get the value of acknowledgment sent from message broker at line 1

```
try {

  ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
      new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);

  // Create a Connection
  Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
  connection.start();

  // Create a Session
  Session session = connection.createSession(true,
      Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

  // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
  Destination destination = session.createQueue(subject);

  // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
  MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
  producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

  // Create a messages
  String text = "Hello world! From Jon";
  TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

   producer.send(message);
  // how to check acknowledgement here? // line1
  session.commit();

  // Clean up
  session.close();
  connection.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As i created  `Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);`
message broker will send the acknowledgement once it receives the message, but how producer will get it?

Comment: what do you mean by `the acknowledgement`?  do you mean that the send succeeded or some type of response from the processor of the message?

Comment: @Martin updated my post to clarify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no visible acknowledgement sent from Broker to producer.  In the non-TX case the send method will only return once the broker has ack'd it unless you configure the client to always send async or you send a non-persistent message.  In the TX case the messages are always sent async unless you configure the always sync send option.  The sync point in the TX case is the commit call which will not return until the messages have been persisted and the TX ends.